# jQuery sliding function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a working jQuery sliding function that I have posted here below. I got it from another question on this site. It's great. Except I now want it to go the opposite direction.

I used this to slide from left to right. I tried adding a minus sign (-) in the animate function to make it {'-width': 'toggle'} but that just made it toggle on and off instead of sliding. I'm sure it's something simple, I'm just frustrated with it.

```
JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pull-me').click(function(){
    $('.panel p').css({
        'width': $('.panel p').width(),
        'height': $('.panel p').height()
    });
    $('.panel').animate({'width': 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

And the html

```
html
<div class="panel">
        <p id="novelDescrip">A website for a local musician to market, stream, and distribute music and merchandise. Content design and development</p>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="slide"><div class="pull-me">Slide Out!</div></p>
```

When I click the More info tab, I want that panel to slide out to the left. Then if they click the More info tab again, it should close back up to the right into the more info tab.

Is there not a way to just reverse the direction of the function i'm already using?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**http://jsfiddle.net/FL87t/3/**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pull-me').click(function(){
        if ($('.panel').is(":hidden")) 
        {
            $('.panel').show('slide', { direction : 'left'}, 500);
        }
        else
        {
            $('.panel').hide('slide', { direction : 'right'}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You are correct. Fixed that. This slides right to left as you saw in the Fiddle. Do you know how to reverse the direction of the slide?

Comment: I should specify, it should be hidden, then when clicked reveal itself by sliding to the left

Comment: Almost, it's hiding itself correctly, but i'm trying to have it anchored on the right so when you click it, the reveal comes out to the left instead of coming back around like that. Does that make sense? I can post a picture if needed.

Comment: @thenewsseattle I just added the image

Comment: Is my original function not animating the css?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: 
http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

Read through it and you should find what your looking for. 
Bare in mind that JQuery also has: `.slideDown() & .slideUp()`
But for changing the animation itself you're probably going to need **CSS**.

This goes in the opposite direction and sort of matches what you want to do in the image you just posted, try building off of it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FL87t/6)

Comment: My first function that I posted does animate the CSS, correct? It does work, but I just want it to go in the opposite direction.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FL87t/6/ <-Try working off of this fiddle I made. And the first function you posted does animate the CSS, you are correct.